# Codeigniter not allowing a specific & symbol in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

The following URl results in an error which says: "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

http://example.com/index.php?/Paypal/success&tx=8T317791V7961045T&st=Completed&amt=20%2e00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=

However, if I simply change the & symbol after 'success' to ? like below then everything works fine despite the fact that there are other & symbols in the URL as well. What is going on here?

http://example.com/index.php?/Paypal/success?tx=8T317791V7961045T&st=Completed&amt=20%2e00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=

How do I make it so that the & symbol after 'success' is accepted? I tried doing the following in Config.php but it didn't work:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\&';
```

OR

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-&';
```

When I tried this I got the 404 Page Not Found error:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?=&';
```

Comment: Did you try change `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` to  `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

Comment: Yes it is already `'QUERY_STRING';`

Answer (score 0):

I presume "/Paypal/success" is a controller + function, and the correct way to put a query string in codeigniter with 
`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` is:

http://example.com/index.php/Paypal/success?tx=8T317791V7961045T&st=Completed&amt=20%2e00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=

Answer (score 0):

The urls in codeigniter are urldecoded, so %27 translates to ' which wasn't on your allowed character list and therefore triggered the error. So you need to allow the characters once decoded. In other words, by the time codeigniter sees you %27, it's already decoded into a '.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@&\-!';
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about Ashu because there is no %27 or ' in the link as far as I can tell. Nevertheless, I have tried your solution but the result is the same. :(

Comment: try this $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+&-';